# Wrong GenericForeignKey name in _meta.get_all_field_names()

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class First(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='n/a')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + ' > ' + self.name


class Second(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='n/a')
    r = generic.GenericRelation(First)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + ' > ' + self.name
```

When I do:

```
from myapp.models import First
First._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

I get:

```
['content_type', u'id', 'name', 'object_id', 'second']
```

So it seems like instead of `content_object`, `GenericForeignKey` named as `second` here. Is it expected behavior?

ps
Im using Django 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

A `GenericForeignKey` uses *two* fields behind the scenes; in this case they are `content_type` and `object_id` since [those are the default names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey). `second` was [created by the `GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericRelation) on `Second.r`.

Answer (score 1):

https://django-model-internals-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_all_field_names.html

> get_all_field_names
>   Returns a list of all field names that are
>   possible for this model (including reverse relation names). This is
>   used for pretty printing debugging output (a list of choices), so any
>   internal-only field names are not included.

In this case, the reverse relation name is `second`. Yes, expected behavior.